# How export list in excel file

Tags: 2010, list-view, excel, export, splist

I want to create a button that exports specific list into the excel file. But when I do it I always get the same error:

> Error List does not exist. The page you selected contains a list that
>   does not exist. It may have been deleted by another use

How can it be possible? List exists, because I get id from object model so I should get a `NullReferenceException` otherwise. Here is my code:

```
<input type="button" onclick="window.location.href='<%= ExcelUrl %>';" value ="Export data"/>
```

code:

```
    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        string listName = Lang.Localize("xxx", "List_Measures");
        using (var site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.ID))
        using (var web = site.OpenWeb(SPContext.Current.Web.ID))
        {
            var list = web.Lists[listName];
            const string relativeUrlMask = @"_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?CS=109&Using=_layouts/query.iqy&List={0}&View={1}&CacheControl=1";                
            ExcelUrl = new Uri(new Uri(site.Url), string.Format(relativeUrlMask, list.ID.ToString("B"), list.DefaultView.ID.ToString("B"))).AbsoluteUri;
        }
        base.OnPreRender(e);
    }
```

finally I get an url:

http://mysite/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?CS=109&Using=_layouts/query.iqy&List=%7B27f5c5b6-e01d-4951-8be5-b31a72eda0e2%7D&View=%7Be518453d-c622-4f31-a0e7-09179f67dce3%7D&CacheControl=1

and it throws this exception. How make it work?

---

usage of `web.Url` instead of `site.Url` doesn't work

---

Now i get correct url, but have another problem: it says that I have not enough permissions event if I'm logged under System account. How can it be actually possible?..

Comment: If you copy the URL in browser address bar, does it work then?

Comment: I found the answer, First of all, current web returns parent web, but not actual. Second - should use `CS=65001` instead of `109`. Here is an additional info in the article and comments: http://weblogs.asp.net/wkriebel/LinkToExportToSpreadsheet

Comment: So it was a survey list. Anyways,  one way to check how out of the box export to excel works is by trapping the network traffic using fiddler and use that Url to build one for your application.

Comment: I've got it, but thanks for an advice :)

Answer (score 0):

if you are working with Sharepoint2013 than 2013 provide out of the box service to export sharepoint list to Exel or Access. I have refer This one , you can also try it .

**https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2224034&seqNum=2**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of exporting from SharePoint, you can try importing from Excel through add-ins like http://www.cdata.com/drivers/sharepoint/excel/ (commercial).  The Excel Add-in allows you to connect to Sharepoint lists, and filter data through transact SQL.